# can not create database when using "rails db:migrate" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie with Rails and trying to make a very simple Rails program. My problem is, when I made a Rails program, at first, I had a mistake and created a database named image by this command `rails g scaffold image video title star:integer description:text` then I made this command `rails db:migrate`, when I realized that problem, I deleted image folder and create another folder named Course by this command `rails g scaffold image video title star:integer description:text`. Everything seem ok.

But, my problem is, when I tried this command `rails db:migrate`, I saw that nothing happen.

When I accessed the website http://localhost:3000/courses/new to try to make a new thing, I saw that I can not make anything new.

So, I think that maybe my problem is, I made the image folder before the course folder.

How can I work with this problem ?
Could you please give me some ideas ? Thank you very much.

@Juanse Gimenez here is my schema.rb, sorry for my shortcomings

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_01_08_042733) do
create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "image"
t.string "video"
t.string "title"
t.integer "star"
t.text "description"
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "video"
t.string "title"
t.integer "star"
t.text "description"
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
end
```

@borjagvo thank you for your comment, here is my new.html.erb `<h1>New Course</h1>` it is very simple, so I do not think that it is the reason ?

Comment: Can you show us with an image your schema.rb in`db/schema.rb`, please update the post

Comment: if u want create a database you need run `rake db:create` if you want add a new table to your database you neeed create a migration/model for this, the scaffold  generate this migration/model/view/routes, i dont see in your description that you generated an scaffold for courses

Comment: Thanks @Nguyen for update, I see in your schema the table `courses`, so the migration for this is ok, maybe do you have other problem, run in your bash console `rails c` or `rails console` and try generate a new Course from console with `Course.new`, maybe your have an issue on controller or routes

Comment: Your second `scaffold` command is exactly the same to the first one. That's why it did nothing. You should have done something additional to what you are telling us that created the courses table. Ca you please update your post with the content inside `/app/views/courses/new.html.erb`?